# Connect to MSSQL Server from linux with pdo (odbc driver) charset

Tags: php, sql-server, linux, pdo, encoding

I'm trying to connect to mssql windows database from linux.

I have successfully created the connection through PDO ODBC driver.

The driver is from FreeTDS.

My problem is with the encoding. The mssql database Collation is in SQL_Latin1_General_CP1253_CI_AI and the table columns has the same collation.

When i connect to database from Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio and run the query i get the correct results.

When i make the query from the linux server (php with pdo) the characters are not the same.

Example:

```
Correct Result => SMA
Incorrect Result (from php) -> S??
```

The odbc.ini has the following lines

```
[SQLServer]
Driver=FreeTDS
Description=SQL Connect
Trace=Yes
Server=serverip
Port=1433
charset=UTF-8
Database=dbname
TDS_Version=8.0
```

The odbcinst.ini has the following lines

```
[FreeTDS]
Description = tdsodbc
Driver = /usr/lib64/libtdsodbc.so.0
Setup = /usr/lib64/libtdsS.so.2
Trace=Yes
TraceFile=/tmp/freetds.log
FileUsage=1
UsageCount=1
client charset=utf-8
```

The freetds.ini has the following lines

```
[SQLServer]
host=serveruo
port=1433
tds version=8.0
```

php code

```
try {
    $pdo = new PDO("odbc:SQLServer", $user, $pass);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "Failed to connect:" . $e->getMessage(); exit;
}
$results = $pdo->query("select ID,Descr from Suppliers", PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
foreach($results as $row) {
    echo $row->Descr;
    echo mb_detect_encoding($row->Descr, mb_detect_order(), true)
}
```

The mb_detected_encoding results are

```
ASCII
```

How can i get the correct result from php?